# Использование различных скобок в принимаемой строке

Tags: java

На вход подается строка-пример. Мне нужно вывести ошибку, если скобки распределены неправильно. Условие: '(' = '{' == '[' и '}' = ']' = ')', все равны по выполняемой функции. То есть могут прислать: {(6+{6+8})+[6+7]}.

Мне нужно вывести ошибку, когда скобки неправильно распределены, скажем '(' - открывающая, а закрывающая '}'.

Пытался реализовать, через рекурсию, но работает только, когда скобки невложенные, таким же образом работает, когда пытаюсь условными операторами при встрече какой-либо скобки в строке менять булевые переменные и работать с ними. Каким способом возможна реализация?

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть в обратную польскую натацию, пример
https://github.com/iagulevich/IntervaleCalculate/blob/master/src/main/java/ru/intervale/calculator/algorithm/ReversePolishNotation.java

Answer (score 1):

В задаче про скобки не нужна рекурсия, а нужен стек открытых скобок и определение пар скобок.

```js
function checkBrackets(expression) {
  var openToClose = { "[": "]", "{": "}", "(": ")" };
  var closeToOpen = { "]": "[", "}": "{", ")": "(" };
  
  var open = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < expression.length; i++) {
    var c = expression[i];
    if (openToClose[c]) {
      open.push(c);
    } else if (closeToOpen[c]) {
      if (open[open.length - 1] == closeToOpen[c]) {
        open.pop();
      } else {
        console.log("Error: mismatch at", i + 1, c);
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  if (open.length) {
    console.log("Error: more open than close");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(checkBrackets("{(6+{6+8})+[6+7]}"));
console.log(checkBrackets("{(6+{6+8})+[6+7]}}"));
```

Comment: Что это за язык? На java не похож...

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець Именно что похож ) - JAVA*script*